# breezejs: is it possible to create a 'not in' predicate?

Tags: breeze

I know how to use the 'in' predicate:

```
 var predicate = new breeze.Predicate('id', 'in', ['value1', 'value2']);
```

but is it possible to do a 'not in' and if so, what is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'not' any predicate.

```
var predicate = new breeze.Predicate('id', 'in', ['value1', 'value2']);
var predicate2 = predicate.not();
```